# Candidatos cuyo promedio es menor al promedio general

Tags: mysql, sql

Deseo completar esta sentencia SQL, para que me retorne solo los candidatos cuyo promedio es menor al promedio general:

```
SELECT Candidato, COUNT(Candidato) AS num_votos
FROM votos
GROUP BY Candidato
```

La estructura de la tabla es:

```
CREATE TABLE votos ( 
    Id int(11) NOT NULL, 
    Candidato varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    Genero varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
    Edad tinyint(4) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

El conteo de votos lo esta haciendo de acuerdo a las veces que se repite el nombre del candidato en la columna candidatos.

Comment: **
CREATE TABLE `votos` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Candidato` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Genero` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Edad` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
**

Comment: el conteo de votos lo esta haciendo de acuerdo a las veces que se repite el nombre del candidato en la columna candidatos

Comment: Fred: utiliza [edit] para añadir estas informaciones :)

Comment: Fred si estas creando la tabla, es decir, no es una estructura heredada que no puedes modificar, deberías replantearte la estructura de la tabla, ya que vas a tener un alto número de registros repetidos, cuando sólo deberías tener un registro por cada candidato, género y edad diferentes, e ir sumando en nuevo campo los votos. La información repetida sólo va a hacer más pesada tu base de datos y más lentas las consultas. Además, si he entendido bien la consulta que planteas, deberías agrupar por candidato, género y edad, ya que dos candidatos diferentes pueden tener el mismo nombre.

Answer (score 3):

Primero que todo Generemos registros de prueba:

```sql
INSERT INTO `votos` (`Id`,`Candidato`,`Genero`,`Edad`) VALUES (1,"josé","masculino",42),(2,"josé","masculino",42),(3,"neder","masculino",28),(4,"josé","masculino",42),(5,"neder","masculino",28),(6,"josé","masculino",42),(7,"josé","masculino",42),(8,"josé","masculino",42),(9,"josé","masculino",42),(10,"neder","masculino",28);
INSERT INTO `votos` (`Id`,`Candidato`,`Genero`,`Edad`) VALUES (11,"neder","masculino",28),(12,"neder","masculino",28),(13,"josé","masculino",42),(14,"hector","masculino",37),(15,"josé","masculino",42),(16,"hector","masculino",37),(17,"hector","masculino",37),(18,"josé","masculino",42),(19,"neder","masculino",28),(20,"hector","masculino",37);
```

---

```
+----+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
| Id | Candidato | Genero    | Edad |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+----+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  1 | josé      | masculino |   42 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  2 | josé      | masculino |   42 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  3 | neder     | masculino |   28 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  4 | josé      | masculino |   42 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  5 | neder     | masculino |   28 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  6 | josé      | masculino |   42 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  7 | josé      | masculino |   42 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  8 | josé      | masculino |   42 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  9 | josé      | masculino |   42 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
| 10 | neder     | masculino |   28 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 11 | neder     | masculino |   28 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 12 | neder     | masculino |   28 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 13 | josé      | masculino |   42 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
| 14 | hector    | masculino |   37 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 15 | josé      | masculino |   42 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
| 16 | hector    | masculino |   37 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 17 | hector    | masculino |   37 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 18 | josé      | masculino |   42 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
| 19 | neder     | masculino |   28 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 20 | hector    | masculino |   37 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
```

> Generador usado http://www.generatedata.com/?lang=es
>
> Terminal en linea de MySQL: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql_terminal_online.php

Ahora en base a los registros anteriores, se supone que deseas obtener de entre (josé, neder y hector) solo aquellos que no superan el promedio del total de votos para cada candidato, algo que puedes hacer es almacenar primero en una variable de sesión este promedio, así:

```sql
SELECT @promedio:=AVG(num_votos)
FROM (
    SELECT Candidato, COUNT(Candidato) AS num_votos
    FROM votos
    GROUP BY Candidato
) AS tabla_promedio;
```

---

```
+---------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                
| @promedio:=AVG(num_votos) |                                                                                                                                                                                                
+---------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                
|               6.666666666 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
+---------------------------+
```

Luego simplemente haces una consulta donde usas esa variable de sesión como  filtro;

```sql
SELECT Candidato, COUNT(Candidato) AS num_votos
FROM votos
GROUP BY Candidato
HAVING num_votos < @promedio;
```

---

```
+--------------+-----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                 
| Candidato    | num_votos |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
+--------------+-----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                 
| hector       |         4 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
| neder        |         6 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
+--------------+-----------+
```

---

### PD: Recomendación

Debes tener en cuenta que el diseño que implementas no es optimo,puesto que no se encuentra normalizado en lo mas mínimo y por tanto no aprovecha las enseñanzas que promueven las bases de datos relacionales. Para ser mas claro te  mostrare el siguiente ejemplo:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
| Id | Candidato | Genero    | Edad |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+----+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  1 | josé      | masculino |   42 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  2 | josé      | masculino |   78 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  3 | neder     | masculino |   53 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  4 | josé      | masculino |   27 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  5 | neder     | masculino |   63 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  6 | josé      | femenino  |   28 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  7 | josé      | masculino |   66 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  8 | josé      | masculino |   28 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  9 | josé      | masculino |   59 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
| 10 | neder     | masculino |   54 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 11 | neder     | masculino |   26 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 12 | neder     | masculino |   71 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 13 | josé      | masculino |   80 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
| 14 | hector    | masculino |   25 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 15 | josé      | masculino |   71 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
| 16 | hector    | masculino |   37 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 17 | hector    | masculino |   72 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 18 | josé      | femenino  |   66 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
| 19 | neder     | masculino |   49 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 20 | hector    | masculino |   74 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
```

Date cuenta que existen diferentes edades para una misma persona, incluso josé llega a cambiar de sexualidad en algunas ocasiones, a esto se le denomina redundancia de datos, pero es algo en lo que no entraré en gran detalle, sin embargo te bosquejare una guía:

> Tabla de candidatos

```
+----+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
| Id | Candidato | Genero    | Edad |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+----+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  1 | josé      | masculino |   42 |                                                                                                                                                                                         
|  3 | neder     | masculino |   53 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 14 | hector    | masculino |   74 |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
```

> Tabla de votos

```
+----+-------------+                                                                                                                                                                                     
| Id | IdCandidato |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 1           |
|  2 | 1           |
|  3 | 3           |
|  4 | 1           |
|  5 | 3           |
|  6 | 1           |
|  7 | 1           |
|  8 | 1           |
|  9 | 1           |
| 10 | 3           |
| 11 | 3           |
| 12 | 3           |
| 13 | 1           |
| 14 | 14          |
| 15 | 1           |
| 16 | 14          |
| 17 | 14          |
| 18 | 1           |
| 19 | 3           |
| 20 | 14          |
+----+-------------+
```

En este caso en la tabla candidatos solo tienes información competente a estos y no existen registros duplicados, josé ahora podrá disfrutar de sexualidad definida y cada integrante del grupo electoral posee una edad única.
Fijate entonces que en la tabla votos, relacionas cada registro a un candidato a través de su `Id`, ahora podrás llevar un conteo de los votos de una mejor manera y será a este quien uses como agrupador.

```sql
SELECT @promedio:=AVG(num_votos)
FROM (
    SELECT Candidato, COUNT(Candidato) AS num_votos
    FROM candidatos
    GROUP BY Candidato
) AS tabla_promedio;
```

---

```sql
SELECT Candidato, COUNT(Candidato) AS num_votos
FROM votos
INNER JOIN candidatos ON voto.IdCandidato = candidato.Id
GROUP BY Candidato
HAVING num_votos < @promedio;
```

Veras que ahora la única diferencia es la linea `INNER JOIN candidatos ON voto.IdCandidato = candidato.Id` esto lo único que define es que ahora para obtener los nombres de los candidatos debes juntar los registros correspondientes de la tabla `votos` y la tabla `candidatos` puesto que como es evidente el campo `candidatos` no existe en la primera.

Espero no haber terminado por confundirlos y que les sea de utilidad.

Comment: He añadido una recomendación, que espero tengan en cuenta para este tipo de diseños. Es muy simple y aun se puede optimizar mas, pero es solo una guiá de arranque.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, deberías mostrar tu tabla completa, aún así voy a suponer que tu tabla tiene la columna **Candidato** y la columna **Votos** y que tu tabla se llama **tablaVotos**:

```
select Candidato, Votos
    from   tablaVotos
    where  Votos < (select avg(Votos)
                     from   tablaVotos);
```

Esa consulta te devuelve los valores que son menor al promedio, si tienes alguna duda al respecto, no dudes en comunicármela.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, saludos!!